# asp css class not working

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I'm having some trouble getting classes to work in asp and css, using ID's in css works fine though, I'm creating the panels via a foreach like so:

```
 foreach(var prodItems in imgList.Zip(titleList.Zip(descList.Zip(stockList, Tuple.Create), Tuple.Create), Tuple.Create))
    {
        System.Web.UI.WebControls.Panel pan = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Panel();
        pan.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Left;
        pan.Height = 100;
        pan.ID = "prodPanel" + intProductCount;
        pan.Attributes.Add("class", "prodPanel");
        form1.Controls.Add(pan);
    }
```

The result comes out as this:

```
 <div id="prodPanel1" class="prodPanel" style="height:100px;text-align:left;"></div>
```

and that seems to be correct to me.

The css:

```
.prodPanel{

margin-bottom:25px;
padding: 14px 16px;
background-color:rgba(0,85,128,0.7);
border-radius: 25px;
text-align:center
}
```

When I run this code the css does not get applied at all! (I'm using this css in the same document so it's defined)

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks!

Comment: add !important to each style element in your class to be applied

Comment: That did not fix the problem unfortunately (you mean this right? " margin-bottom:25px !important;") EDIT: nvm that fixed it, had to ctrl + F5 Thanks!

Comment: I didn't understand. does your problem fixed??